# Is there a way to have default mesh objects come with premarked UV unwrapping seams?

Tags: texturing, uv, edit-mode

I was thinking it might be useful to have default mesh object such as cubes, cylinders or other objects like the platonic solids etc from addons to default to come with premarked UV unwrapping seams when added to a scene. Is there a way to do this, perhaps with the startup file? Here is an example of what I was thinking about:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK these objects are generated based on instructions in the code (it doesn't use "template" objects or anything like that). The only things I can think of are: **1.** editing the source code of blender (and any addons which add new primitives) to generate meshes with seams, or **2.** Creating your own seamed primitives with [CreaPrim](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256602-Addon-EWOCprojects-presents-CreaPrim). (I'm not sure if it keeps the seams, I haven't tested this)

Comment: AFAIK, this is supported in some softwares such as TrueSpace, but not yet implemented into Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

This creates a UV layout for an object on creation and is a feature in 2.77. You can download RC2 from the institute now.